# Go: best practice for safely converting integers to protocol buffer enum values

Tags: go, enums, type-conversion, protocol-buffers

I have an enum in a proto file that generates to integer constants in the pb.go file. I now have some integers coming from the an external data source and want to safely map them to the possible constants.

Here is what I currently have: https://play.golang.org/p/-5VZqPbukd

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

//enum in the proto file
//
// enum X {
//    A = 0;
//    B = 1;
//    C = 2;
//    D = 3;
// }

//enum type generated by protoc
type X int32

//enum constants generated by protoc
const (
    X_A X = 0
    X_B X = 1
    X_C X = 2
    X_D X = 3
)

func intToX(v int) (X, error) {
    x := X(v)
    switch x {
    case X_A, X_B, X_C, X_D:
        return x, nil
    }
    return 0, errors.New("could not convert int to X")
}

func main() {
    for i := -1; i < 10; i++ {
        if x, err := intToX(i); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("unhandled error:", err, "for input value", i)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%d => X(%d)\n", i, x)
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**: Is there a better, more idiomatic way to map incoming integer values to protoc-generated constants?

In particular, I would like to avoid listing all constants explicitly in the `case A, B, C, D` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know which proto generation package you are using, but with `github.com/golang/protobuf/proto` you also get the reverse mapping of enums.

Example xyz.pb.go generated file:

```
type TimeInterval int32

const (
    TimeInterval_TI_UNKNOWN TimeInterval = 0
    TimeInterval_TI_HOUR    TimeInterval = 1
    TimeInterval_TI_DAY     TimeInterval = 2
    TimeInterval_TI_WEEK    TimeInterval = 3
    TimeInterval_TI_MONTH   TimeInterval = 4
    TimeInterval_TI_QUARTER TimeInterval = 5
    TimeInterval_TI_YEAR    TimeInterval = 6
)

var TimeInterval_name = map[int32]string{
    0: "TI_UNKNOWN",
    1: "TI_HOUR",
    2: "TI_DAY",
    3: "TI_WEEK",
    4: "TI_MONTH",
    5: "TI_QUARTER",
    6: "TI_YEAR",
}
var TimeInterval_value = map[string]int32{
    "TI_UNKNOWN": 0,
    "TI_HOUR":    1,
    "TI_DAY":     2,
    "TI_WEEK":    3,
    "TI_MONTH":   4,
    "TI_QUARTER": 5,
    "TI_YEAR":    6,
}

func (x TimeInterval) String() string {
    return proto.EnumName(TimeInterval_name, int32(x))
}
func (TimeInterval) EnumDescriptor() ([]byte, []int) { return fileDescriptor0, []int{0} }
```

So with this you could test for existence in the following manner:

```
if _, found := TimeInterval_name[testinputint]; found{
    //all ok
} else {
   //not a value for this enum
}
```

Comment: Yes! I now also found the `X_name` map and use `if _, ok := X_name[int32(v)]; ok { return X(v), nil }
` to test the values. Btw. if you want the credit for this answer you should stick to the example. And are you sure about your `found, _` statement. I guess you need to write `_, found` here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @RickyA mentions using a range is nice as it verifies for all the possible underlying const values.

Additionally you could check the length of the enum, although that would only be possible when the underlying enum values do not have any 'gaps' and have a consequitive range of numbers.

Verbose explanation via code:

```
typelength := int32(len(TimeInterval_name))
if testinputint < 0 || int32(testinputint) >= typelength {
    // not a value for this enum, return err
}
```

A bit less verbose, and just using int instead of int32

```
if testinputint < 0 || int(testinputint) >= len(TimeInterval_name) {
    // not a value for this enum, return err 
}
```

But as said, this will only be valid for enums that adhere to a proper iota. That might not be the case when you have changed your enum to read something like this:

```
var TimeInterval_name = map[int32]string{
    0: "TI_UNKNOWN",
    1: "TI_HOUR",
    2: "TI_DAY",
    3: "TI_WEEK",
    // we do not use month anymore 4: "TI_MONTH",
    5: "TI_QUARTER",
    6: "TI_YEAR",
}
```

as the length of the generated map will be clearly less than six :)

In other words use the found method of @Ricky_A above to keep on the safe side.